# Discount percentage of a given date vb6

Tags: date, vb6, percentage

i need code in vb6 make that

[image]

examble:

> 13"days" - 10% = 11"days" , 16"hours" , 48"minutes"

i try this:

1-  i convert days to minutes

> (13*24*60) = 18720

2.

```
Dim Result As Double
Result = ((100 - 10) / 100) * 18720
Text3.Text = Result   '"text3.text=16848"
```

now how can format result to DD HH NN ? 
THANKS

Comment: Re-convert back, of course.

Comment: how re-convert  in code @Giorgio_Brausi ?

Comment: Result / 24 / 60, will return 11,7.

Answer (score 0):

Like this using LEFT/MID/RIGHT keyword

```
Dim Result As Double
Dim Dayz, Hourz, MinuteZ As String
'
'Using your formula - which i have not checked
Result = ((100 - 10) / 100) * 18720
'
'extract values
Dayz = Left(Result,2)
Hourz = Mid(Result, 3, 2)
Minutez = Right(Result, 2)
'concatenate
Text3.Text = (Dayz & " Days, " & Hourz & " Hours, " & Minutez & " Minutes.")
```

You can also look into the FORMAT command.